# For-loop conditions checking PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, control-flow

I am writing PHP code with a for-loop:

```
for($i=1;$i<=count($ArrayData);$i++){
  //some code that changes the size of $ArrayData
}
```

Does the program check the loop condition `($i<=count($ArrayData))` every time or only once?

Thanks

Comment: It will loop as long as the condition is met. So yes, it is checked every iteration. How is the loop supposed to know when to stop otherwise?

Comment: I think you mean does it calculate the size of the Array once or every time; it has to check the condition every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is checking it every iteration, for example:

```
for($i=1;$i<count($ArrayData);$i++){
    $ArrayData[]=1;
}
```

will last until memory is exhausted, it will yield for example:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted

To change it to checking only once once, use this:

```
for($i=1,$c =count($ArrayData); $i<=$c;$i++){
    $ArrayData[]=1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Every time.
From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php):

> ```
> for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
> ```
>
> ...
>   In the beginning of each iteration, `expr2` is evaluated. If it evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues and the nested statement(s) are executed. If it evaluates to FALSE, the execution of the loop ends.

This can also be verified by using a snippet like:

```
<?php
function compare($i)
{
    echo 'called'.PHP_EOL;
    return $i < 5;
}
for($i = 0; compare($i); $i++) {}
```

which should print:

```
called
called
called
called
called
called
```

(Note that the 6th time `compare` is called, it returns `FALSE`, but still prints `called`.)

**[ [Demo](http://3v4l.org/oIWm3) ]**

Answer (score 0):

As `$i` is incremented in every iteration. Condition is also checked in every iteration against new value of `$i` as long as loop is running.